# How do i know the process ID of the parent process?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a script with loop like

```
while read host
do
./script &
done
```

I want to know the process id of the current process which is starting the ./script in background and use it in script.

Comment: but `$$` does not work inside script which is in background

Comment: Oops! sorry goldi i nade a mistake mistakenly i edited your comment

Comment: You didn't; I deleted it and made it an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming a POSIX shell (like `bash`), `$$` is the PID of the current shell and `$PPID` is the PID of the parent. You can pass `$$` to the script or check the value of `$PPID` in the script.

Answer (score 3):

The process ID of the current shell is in the special variable `$$`.

You can pass this to a forked (backgrounded) process:

```
./script $$ &
```

In "script", that will be the first argument, so:

```
parent_pid=$1
```

There's a summary of [bash special variables here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html).